# Whats the point of scaling VMs/containers on the same server?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, scalability

If you have a host machine with say 3 VMS (or docker containers) running a different service each, whats the point of adding a replica of one of these VMs/containers on the same host machine or when would you need to do so? If the host machine is under a lot of traffic which will lead to problems with CPU utilization and memory, how will creating even more instances help?

Docker swarm also allows users to create new instances of a running container without adding new nodes to the cluster. How can this possibly help?

Comment: I am not entirely sure if this would really be the way to be done but if your container service only utilizes single thread such as `nodeJS` (of course you can cluster it within the container too and that's why I'm saying I'm not sure) it could potentially be more flexible in a way that you get a high level control?

Answer (score 0):

When you're traffic is going to your containers you would want more instances of it. With orchestrators such as kubernetes you can spread your instances across many hosts and make them accessible with a single address.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that replicas are supposed to be on the same host is wrong.
The very idea of replicas is supposed to provide fault-tolerance, and thus they need to be on different hosts so that if one host goes down, your service is still available on the different node. [Think node clusters]
That said, there's nobody stopping you from creating the new instances on the same node, but that makes no sense and provides no added advantage of fault-tolerance.

Coming to the part where you say, if host machine is already under stress due to loads, how will it help to spawn new instance there?
Well, it won't. That is precisely why we spawn it on a different node on the cluster. And with the same IP, Kubernetes/Docker swarm makes sure to load-balance between each of them.

Comment: So therefore in docker swarm theres no point in having more replicas than nodes?

Comment: @ninesalt Pretty much, yes. But not always. Sorry but the answer is not that simple. Since you said there's only one host machine, you can stretch the resources only so much. So for your question, I'd say you need multiple hosts to actually scale properly. But there will always be a case where it makes more sense to have multiple replicas on same host. For eg: Your application is not really using CPU or IO pretty intensively, in that case rather than horizontal scaling, you can always do vertical scaling. Basically you add more containers than throw more hardware into the pool.

Answer (score 0):

Container-level scaling increases fault-tolerance.
Node-level scaling increases throughput.

You might just run all services on 1 node (e.g. 1 VM), and when it is overloaded, add another instance. This is fine for on-demand resources, such as CPU and disk IO: They are unused when idle, but each service will also add some fixed overhead, like RAM or database connections. So you will waste this when scaling up everything rather than just the containers.

By being able to scale both on the container level and node level, you can add resources to your cluster (RAM, CPU), but only allocate it to the services needing it.

So the scaling should be something like this:

Node 1:

- service A
- service B
- service C

Node 2:

- service A
- service B

Node 3:

- service B

Any doubles per node just helps with fault tolerance.